# $\left(\int_{t}^{s}|f'(x)|\mathrm{d}x\right)^{2} \leq \int_{t}^{s}|f'(x)|^{2}\mathrm{d}x$ is true?

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove or disprove:
>
> (a) If $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^{1}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|^{2}\mathrm{d}t\leq M^{2} < \infty$ then $|f(s) - f(t)| \leq M\sqrt{|s - t|}$ for any $s,t \in (0,1)$.
>
> (b) For any $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ and $D > 0$, is possible to find $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^{1}$ e $s_{0},t_{0} \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|\mathrm{d}t < 1$ and $|f(s_{0}) - f(t_{0})| > D|s_{0} - t_{0}|^{\alpha}$.

For (a): Suppose (WLG) $s \geq t$, so
$$|f(s) - f(t)|^{2} = \left|f(0) + \int_{0}^{s}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x - \left(f(0) + \int_{0}^{t}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\right|^{2} = \left|\int_{t}^{s}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x \right|^{2} \leq \left(\int_{t}^{s}|f'(x)|\mathrm{d}x\right)^{2}.$$

Here's my question about (a):

$$\left(\int_{t}^{s}|f'(x)|\mathrm{d}x\right)^{2} \leq \int_{t}^{s}|f'(x)|^{2}\mathrm{d}x$$
is true?

For (b): I have no idea how to start. I spent a lot of time trying to find counterexamples, which makes me think to be true, but I also don't know how to prove

Comment: Part a): Cauchy-Schwartz. That’s not true in general.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong before. You are right. Cauchy-Schwartz is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

That $(\int_{t}^s |f'(x)|dx)^2 \leq \int_{t}^s |f'(x)|^2dx$ is true in this case, that's a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\int_{t}^s|f'(x)|dx \leq \left(\int_t^s|f'(x)|^2dx \right)^{1/2}\left( \int_t^s 1^2dx\right)^{1/2} \implies \\
 \implies \left(\int_{t}^s|f'(x)|dx \right)^2 \leq \underbrace{\sqrt{s-t}}_{\leq 1}\int_t^s|f'(x)|^2dx 
$$

For $a)$, you just apply this result (not using the last step though):
\begin{align*}
|f(s)-f(t)| \leq \int_{t}^s |f'(x)|dx &\leq \left(\int_t^s|f'(x)|^2dx \right)^{1/2}\left( \int_t^s 1^2dx\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq M\sqrt{s-t}.
\end{align*}

For $b)$, let $C,\varepsilon>0$ be constants we'll choose in a minute and $f(x) = Cx^{1/2}$. Pick $C>0$ small such that $\int |f'(x)|dx < 1$. Now, put $t_0 = \varepsilon$ and $s_0=4\varepsilon$ (for $\varepsilon<1/4)$. Then,
$$
\frac{|f(s_0)-f(t_0)|}{|s_0-t_0|^\alpha} = \frac{C}{3^\alpha}\frac{\varepsilon^{1/2}}{\varepsilon^\alpha} = \frac{C}{3^\alpha}\frac{1}{\varepsilon^{\alpha-1/2}}.
$$
Since $\alpha-1/2>0$, if $\varepsilon\to 0$ the quantity above goes to infinity. In particular, for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, it gets larger than $D$. Picking such $\varepsilon$, we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

For a), since $x^2$ is convex, we may apply Jensen's inequality to see that:
$$\frac{1}{(s-t)^2}(\int_t^s|f'(x)|\,dx)^2\leq\frac{1}{s-t}\int_t^s|f'(x)|^2\,dx\implies(\int_t^s|f'(x)|\,dx)^2\leq(s-t)\int_t^s|f'(x)|^2\,dx\leq \int_t^s|f'(x)|^2\,dx$$
since $s-t<1$.